# JavaScript: Better solution than delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var example = [
    function() { /* hello */ },
    function() { /* goodbye */ }
];
```

I use `delete example[0];` and am left with the following result:

```
var example = [
    1: function() { /* goodbye */ }
];
```

Is there a better solution than `delete`? Or is there a simple way to fix the indexes in the array? (I have jQuery at my disposal)

**Edit**: I fixed the example array. The indexes were there for the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `example` is an array, instead of `delete`, you can use [`.splice` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
example.splice(0, 1);
```

But if `examples` is actually an object, you'd have to use `delete` and iterate over all properties and "rename" them. Though it's probably easier to use an array instead.

The reason why you get this result with `delete` is that you are removing the property `'0'` from the underlying object and the property `'1'` still exists. You are basically operating on a lower level.

Another problem with gaps in the indexes is that `array.length` will always return the the highest index + 1 and not the actual number of values in the array. So after deleting the element, `example.length` would still be `2`.

Comment: `[].shift()` would work as well. As would `[].pop()` if you wanted to delete it from the end of the array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of defining an array is wrong.
This is how its done:

```
var example = [
    function() { /* hello */ },
    function() { /* goodbye */ }
];
```

you can use shift to remove the first element:

```
var firstElement = example.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom sort function:

```
array.sort(sortfunction)

function sortfunction(a, b){
  // check indexes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just shift your first element.

http://jsfiddle.net/4zW7B/1/

```
var example = [
    function() { alert('hello'); },
    function() { alert('goodbye'); }
];
example[0]();
example.shift();
example[0]();
```